# are there any lag fixes for Samsung Galaxy S that don't require rooting the phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

It seems like the Samsung Galaxy S is notorious for its occasional lag.  Various lag fixes are out, but most of them require me to root my phone.

I am reluctant to void the warranty on my phone, so I would like to avoid rooting it if possible.

Are there any lag fixes out there that don't require me to root the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

You can lagfix without rooting by flashing a kernel like Voodoo through Odin.

### But

This will void your warranty anyways.

If it helps, the SGS phones are very easy to unroot and revert to stock to hide what you did.

Comment: So the question should be if there are any lagfixes out that won't void my warranty, right?

Comment: @Nathan Anything that goes beyond what is possible for regular non-root apps voids your warranty, in most cases. And I doubt a regular app can do a real lagfix. The problem on the SGS is the filesystem; changing that is pretty heavy-duty.