# Does updating to 2.3 fix Galaxy S' lag issue?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread

As title. The lag issue I am talking about is the notorious "RFS lag" as explained [here](http://hkdennis2k.homeip.net/2010/11/04/reality-behind-rfs-lag-of-samsung-galaxy-s/), and is also refered to [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/have-samsung-ever-acknowledged-the-lag-issue-on-galaxy-s-phones) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5916/are-there-any-lag-fixes-for-samsung-galaxy-s-that-dont-require-rooting-the-phone)

Answer (score 3):

Although they didn't change the file system, they did make improvements and I'm personally noticing significantly less lag on 2.3.3 coming from 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

From [techie-buzz.com](http://techie-buzz.com/mobile-news/samsung-galaxy-s-android-2-3-gingerbread.html):

> [O]ne major disappointment with this firmware is that it still uses the RFS file system. The RFS FS is the major culprit behind all the lags and stalling issues which majority of the Galaxy S owners face.

If you want to fix your lag I recommend an Ext4 lagfix.  If you flash a kernel such as [Voodoo](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=774500) with Odin, you don't even need to root first (note that flashing it will void your warranty anyways though).  [This guide](http://techgom.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/installing-gingerbread-voodoo-stock-ext4-kernel-on-your-sgs/) describes the process for an Android 2.3.4 kernel for the SGS GT-i9000.

I use Voodoo on my SGS Vibrant and it's awesome.

Comment: Note that flashing Voodoo will automatically root your phone, not including installing the superuser apk from the market.

Comment: @Nathan Hmm, really? How? I'm trying to unpack the kernel zImage without much success but from what I understand it's supposed to write to a specific block of storage (so the flashing itself can't root) and I don't see why supercurio would add code in the kernel to root the phone.

Comment: This is in the guide you linked to: "François Simond a.k.a supercurio the founder of project-voodoo for Galaxy S devices has created a kernel based on ext4 with custom recovery menu and **root(you need to install superuser app from market)**." *(emphasis by Nathan)*

Comment: @Nathan My bad, I should have read that more carefully. I'll try testing later to confirm one way or the other.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this have other consequences? It looks like you are recommending installing a whole new OS. Will it remove features from Samsung, like Samsung Apps, Samsung-specific menus, etc?

Comment: @Louis No, I'm recommending installing a kernel. Supercurio provides stock kernels that are modified to support an ext4 filesystem, that is all. Thanks for bumping this though, I had forgotten to test; favorited the question for later.

Comment: @Nathan I just tested on stock KB5 on my Vibrant. I flashed the `stock+Voodoo-Froyo-T959-UVKB5` kernel and it worked, yet my system is not rooted.  I do not have busybox, su, or the SuperUser app.

Comment: So I'll still have Samsung stock UI and apps? What does installing a kernel exactly do?

Comment: @Louis It's similar to installing a kernel on Linux.  The kernel provides system functions, it's the core of the OS.  The most noticeable change between kernels is normally battery life and speed, it definitely doesn't affect apps or your launcher.

Answer (score 1):

2.2.1 was the big lag fix release on the Galaxy S, that made a huge difference to the device's speed compared to the previous 2.1 and 2.2 releases.

To me, the Gingerbread 2.3.3 feels very much the same to me as 2.2.1 did.